# confusion with .closest() .siblings() .find()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<div id="wrapf">

<div class="dropsf">
  <select name="f" class="food">
    <option value="" rel="">Choose!</option>
    <option value="1" rel="2">1</option>
    <option value="3" rel="6">2</option>
    <option value="7" rel="14">3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="serve">
 <button id="plus">+</button>
 <input id="srv" name="srv" class="srv" type="text" value="1" size="2" readonly="readonly"/>
 <button id="minus">-</button>
</div>

</div><!-- #wrapf -->
```

I had this code before I added a few `<div>` to the above code (for alignment and CSS reasons):

```
var food = $(".food"),
    cc = [],
    gc = [];

    //Push values into an array.
for(var i = 0; i < food.length; i++) {
  var v = food.eq(i).find('option:selected').val();
  var m = food.eq(i).siblings('input[name=srv]').val();
    gc.push(food.eq(i).find('option:selected').attr('rel'));
    cc.push(v * m); 
 }
```

But now my javascript isn't working, and I'm confused over how to get the values from the drop down... (I append each drop down, that's why I'm using the `for` statement), my `v` variable is fine and the `gc.push` statement is working, but my `m` variable isn't registering. I'm trying to get the value from the `serving` input, how can I do this?

ps. I've also tried `.find()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input[name=srv]` is not a sibling of `.food`.  Also, for looping over jQuery objects, I suggest using `.each`.

```
var food = $(".food"),
    cc = [],
    gc = [];

food.each(function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        // you can just get the val of the select
        val = $this.val(),
        // this is the same as $(this).find('option:selected')
        option = $('option:selected', this),
        // or even simpler: $('#srv').val();
        inputVal = $this.parent('.dropsf').siblings('.serve').find('input[name=srv]').val();
    gc.push(option.attr('rel'));
    cc.push(val * inputVal);
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer! This was also a large help, for sake of people landing on this thread, and looking at my code, I'll mark the other one as the answer just because it was only one line change

Comment: for some reason, the `inputVal` variable isn't working.. any ideas?

Comment: oops, just wrote in the class name wrong, I fixed it! your answer works perfectly for me, it's the new right answer! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

```
food.closest('#wrapf').find('input[name=srv]').val()
```

should work

Comment: works perfectly! thanks so much, I'll mark this answer correct when the time limit allows!

Comment: Why `food.closest('#wrapf')` Why not just `$('#wrapf')`?

Comment: @Rocket, true, it could also be just $('#srv').val(); since id's have to be unique as someone pointed out. but using closest and find most of the id's used could be omitted, thus cleaning the html a bit

Answer (score 1):

Isn't id unique? Shouldn't this work then?

```
$("#srv").val()
```

By the way, you don't need to do this:

```
var v = food.eq(i).find('option:selected').val();
```

you can do this (if you do have multiple food items):

```
var v = food.eq(i).val();
```

`val()` gives you the currently selected value already.

Comment: ID isn't unique just because I have a button to append the entire HTML code that I posted, and 2 or 3 of the same drop downs may be visible at once!

Comment: Still, ID's _have_ to be unique. Rocket's solution is probably the way to go then since the identifiers make it more clear what's going on.

Comment: for my application Andy's answer is working so far, I may rewrite to the answer that @Rocket provided! I appreciate your help!